# SQLAlchemy: Auto generate class definitions for a legacy database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How can I auto-generate class definitions for SQLAlchemy, including relationships and backref, as the Django-ORM does with [`manage.py inspectdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/legacy-databases/#auto-generate-the-models)?

Comment: @Ilja Everilä The question was not written as a tool request.  A totally legitimate answer would be an approach for how to write code to do this.  As it happens there's a good tool for the job, and that seems a better answer.

Comment: Harper: to help the unanswered questions queue to stay low consider to check your own answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the python package sqlacodegen for exactly this purpose.

sqlacodegen will inspect the database and generate SQLAlchemy style class definitions for future reference and store them in a file.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlacodegen

Usage:

- `pip install sqlacodegen`
- Start from command line: `sqlacodegen [connection string] [options]`

The generated class definitions are largely correct and include index definitions and constraints (foreign keys).

In my case, it saved me from typing out 19.000 rows of class definitions.

Comment: Hi @Harper
Thanks for sharing, this is a good one but the only problem it works well with SQLAlchemy 1.4 and below
Thanks

Comment: There are multiple forks of sqlacodegen. I am using sqlacodegen_v2, which is available from pypi.org. It's compatible with sqlalchemy 2.

Comment: sqlacodegen was updated 3 weeks ago to work with SQLAlchemy 2.0, version 3.0.0rc5. It's already [available on github](https://github.com/agronholm/sqlacodegen), but not yet via pypi / pip.